# Kosher dish transfer?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization

According to below, we use separate dishes for kosher to avoid transferring "taste". However if we allow butil bashishim in regards to food then how much more so should we allow the same utensils. Taste in a utensil transferring is way less significant than 1/60th? Below is background as per chabad.org (dont know if its necessary to include.)

> In Judaism, Even a small trace of a non-kosher substance—as little as
> 1/60th (1.66 percent) of the food’s volume, and in certain cases, even
> less than that—will render an otherwise kosher food not kosher. By the
> same token, utensils that come in contact with hot food will absorb
> its “taste” and subsequently impart it to other food.
>
> Even the slightest residue or “taste” of a non-kosher substance will
> render a food not kosher. So it’s not enough to buy only kosher food.
> The kitchen, too, must be “kosher,” meaning that all cooking utensils
> and food preparation surfaces are used exclusively for kosher food,
> and that separate stoves, pots, cutlery, dishes, counter surfaces and
> table coverings are used for meat and dairy.

Comment: We don't nullify small amounts of flavor on purpose; that's only for accidents.

Comment: "Taste in a utensil transferring is way less significant than 1/60th" This isn't always obvious. Depends what kind of material it is and what it was used with.

Comment: Also taste is nullified in sixty because we assume it spread evenly. It doesn't necessarily spread evenly in pots/plates etc.

Comment: Obviously if the pot is not clean I agree. But if its a clean pot that was used for meat once, i dont see how the meat taste would be significant at all

Comment: The meat taste in the pot doesn't go anywhere and if you cook with it it'll come out into the dairy food

Comment: Then it would still be less than 1/60th

Comment: You'll surely agree that sometimes things can take on flavors of vessels they were cooked in. Sherry cask liquor is a thing for a reason. Those are the cases where it's more than "1/60" (1/60 being the rabbinic approximation for when perceptible flavor is added)

Comment: The simple answer is that you need to have 60x the metal in the pot and that’s almost impossible.

Comment: Related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/85453/is-batel-beshishim-relevant-to-issues-regarding-pots-pans-utensils

Comment: @Chatzkel That's hardly a simple answer. Really these are all chumras since we pretend we don't have a kfeila. Most rabbis forget that 99% of in-practice kashrut rulings are not actually derabanan nor deorayta, just midin that minhag

Comment: @double AA it might not be the one that’s accepted by all opinions, but in regards to the question asked, is a straight forward simple answer. Once the pot is treif then you can’t use bitul and that’s why we always use separate dishes today.

Comment: This is not a duplicate... There it is asking if it applies whereas here it is asking why it can't be done lechatchila. These appear to be very different questions.

Answer (score 1):

The laws of Kashrut are quite complex. In fact some things might technically be okay even Halachically but women/men have been stringent and this became the custom.

In regard to your question although one could in theory clean a pot and wait 24 hours so that there is no unkosher taste (it becomes פגום). This is Rabbinically prohibited for fear one might accidentally not wait the appropriate time. In addition perhaps one cooks a sharp food that rejuvenates the taste. Similarly Nullifying is not straightforward, first of all it should not be done intentionally ש׳׳ע יורה דעה צט, סע׳ ה.(ie: used as a loophole only as a leniency if done accidentally). See  ש׳׳ך יורה דעה, צט, ס"ק ז who says it is rabbinically prohibited - though some others hold it is prohibited by the Torah.

And so going back to the example of a clean pot cooked after 24 hours, if it was deliberate. Pri Megadim (M.Z. OC 451:2) penalizes him and forbids him to eat the food. Igros Moshe (YD 2:41) disagrees, and although it is forbidden to do this there is no penalty and the food may be eaten.

Similarly it might become very difficult to determine how much of the permitted food is necessary to nullify the pot. For instance when only a kzayis (olive) of milk was used in a clean pot, then it can be nullified with 60x a kazayis. However if you regularly use the pot for milk the day before (without knowledge of the amount) then the whole pot must be nullified see יורה דעה צח:ד. Now if that milk pot had a some meat cooked in it, the pot is now prohibited (due to absorbing milk and meat). No longer can it be nullified against 60x the meat, but instead must be nullified against the 60x the milk and meat, which in this case is the pot once again. This last part is a disagreement see יורה דעה צח:ו and also the ט׳׳ז there. So although 60x can cause nullification it is not always so straightforward and simple.

So it is Rabbinically prohibited so that you not accidentally not clean the pot (mixing actually food stuff), or in case you don't wait the appropriate time (mixing taste), and that intentional nullification of a prohibition is not allowed. Finally even if all these issues were moot, it is not straightforward to nullify things and a Rabbi should be consulted.